# How to configure TSLint one-line for some rules and the opposite for others?

Tags: typescript, tslint

There is the `one-line` config where I can force the code, for example, `else` to go in the same line as the if's `}`.

```
"one-line": [
  true,
  "check-open-brace",
  "check-catch",
  "check-else",
  "check-finally",
  "check-whitespace"
],
```

What I want to do is keep these two as `one-line`

```
"one-line": [
  true,
  "check-open-brace",
  "check-whitespace"
],
```

but force others to go in a separated line

```
"check-catch",
"check-else",
"check-finally",
```

So I can force

```
if () {
}
else {
}
```

I'm currently using TSLint@3.9.0. How can I set this up?

Answer (score 1):

> How to configure TSLint one-line for some rules and the opposite for others?

You basically want a rule like `multiline` for `catch`/`else`/`finally`. Going through : https://github.com/palantir/tslint I don't see such a rule mentioned.

You can request it here : https://github.com/palantir/tslint/issues

Answer (score 0):

There is [tslint-eslint-rules](https://github.com/buzinas/tslint-eslint-rules) packege, which makes possible to run (some) of the eslint rules in tslint. Luckily, the [brace-style](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/brace-style) rule is implemented and your brace-style can be enforced by:

```
"brace-style": ["error", "stroustrup"]
```

(I didn't tried it, it is possible that it requires some tweaking)